# ¿Cómo asignar una IP externa en un servicio de k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

Se quiere desplegar un servicio que escucha por los puertos 8080 y 4000 se tiene el siguiente archivo yaml de configuración.

```
---
  apiVersion: "v1"
  kind: "Service"
  metadata:
    name: "nombremicroservicio"
  spec:
    type: "NodePort"
    selector:
      name: "nombremicroservicio"
    ports:
      -
        name: "http"
        port: 8080
        protocol: "TCP"
      -
        name: "agente"
        port: 4000
        protocol: "TCP"
```

Cuando se verifica el servicio este no le ha relacionado una IP

kubectl get services

```
 NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          
 nombre...    NodePort    10.96.97.18   <none>        8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Para exponer un servicio fuera del cluster k8s con una IP fija, el servicio debe ser de tipo LoadBalancer.

```
  apiVersion: "v1"
  kind: "Service"
  metadata:
    name: nombremicroservicio
  spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    loadBalancerIP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

    selector:
      name: nombremicroservicio
    ports:
    ...
    ...
```